# How to call multiple $http.post requests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm calling a save function in my controller, such as this:

```
vm.save = function(onSaveSuccess, onSaveFailed) {
 var data = {
  "id": vm.id,
  "name": vm.name
 };

 myService.updateData(data)
  .then(function () {
    onSaveSuccess('Saved');
  })
  .catch(onSaveFailed);
}
```

My `updateData()` looks something like this:

```
self.updateData = function(data) {
 return $http.post(url, data).then(returnData);
}
```

This works fine, but now I need to execute multiple POST requests in `updateData`. How do I do that without having to change my `save` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and it will parallel call both APIs and return a promise with an array of results.

```
self.updateData = function(data) {
 return Promise.all([ $http.post(url1, data).then(returnData), $http.post(url2, data).then(returnData) ]);
}
```